# nginx redirect old site urls and modify 1 language suffix only

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want to redirect old site urls to new site. But new site has different page names and language chars have changed too.

for example:

`en/about/info` will redirect to `en/com/information`

but

`ge/about/info` will go to `ka/com/information`

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {

<lang>/about/info/ $lang/com/information/

}
```

any ideas how I would go about this? There are a lot of urls, so I don't want to write these urls hardcoded for each language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` directive can capture parts of a regular expression, but cannot use that capture in the mapped result.

So it is possible to create a named capture called `lang` (for example) and use it *after* the mapped variable is evaluated. For example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect_uri {
~*(?<lang>/\w\w/)about/info/ com/information/;
}
```

And in the `server` or `location` block:

```
if ($redirect_uri) {
    return 301 $lang$redirect_uri;
}
```

Note that `$lang` is only created after the value of `$redirect_uri` is evaluated in the `if` statement.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.